# Completeness proof?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

First of all, this is not a question about a specific problem, but more about a general technique. When I face a problem such as "show that a metric space $(M,d)$ is complete", the first thing I do is to say: if a metric space is complete, then every Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ where $x_n\in M$ for all $n$ converges in $M$. From there, I am clueless as to how to proceed: are we allowed to assume that $(x_n)$ at least converges to *something* that may or may not be in $M$?

Comment: Only if $M$ is a subspace of a complete space.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly a standard method, but there is some grain of truth in what you write. Every metric space can be seen as a sub-space of a complete metric space. Mre precisely, every metric space is isometrically equivalent to a dense subset of a complete metric space and this larger metric space is unique up to isometries.

See the wikipedia page on [metric completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Completion).

Answer (score 0):

No -- that's not quite it. I think that you are contemplating the fact that we can prove $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete by finding a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ which we know has a limit in $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\mathbb{Q}$.  But we can't quite work that strongly by analogy here, because we don't know that $M$ lives in some "larger" space where it has a limit.

Instead, you need to start from the assumption only that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $M$ (that is: given $\epsilon>0$, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lvert x_n-x_m\rvert<\epsilon$ whenever $n,m\geq N$), and show that the sequence must have a limit.

If you have a more specific question in mind, let me know and I'll be happy to try to give you a hint on how to proceed.

Comment: Actually, since for every metric space $(X,d)$ there is a unique (up to isomoprhy) completion $(\bar X, \bar d)$, you actually *do* know that $M$ lies within some larger space where every cauchy sequence has a limit. That won't help much with proving that $X$ is complete, though - you'll have to show that $\bar X = X$, which amounts to showing that all these limits are already in $X$, which brings you back to "every cauchy sequence in $X$ has a limit"...

Comment: @fgp That would, roughly, be why I didn't bring it up.  You are absolutely correct, though.

Comment: Nicholas, thanks for your response. Okay then... what if my sequence is a Cauchy sequence of SETS? Can I then say that there is a set $X$ that serves as a limit of this sequence?

Comment: @user134070 Sets of what? What is the metric?

Comment: I am trying to ask as little as possible, as this is an assignment, but, it LITERALLY is JUST a set. To be specific, I was given a complete metric space $(M,d)$, and this sequence is the sequence of subsets of $M$.

Comment: @user134070 What do you mean by **the** sequence of subsets? This also doesn't answer the question of what metric you're putting on the space of subsets.  I know you're trying to ask as little as possible... but without a clear question, I can't even give you a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: @user134070 If I am right, you are referring to the Haausdorff metric of closed bounded sets, so there the proof is by finding an appropriate candidate for the limit.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, you often *construct* your limit object. It can be by using the completeness of a well-known space, generally $\mathbb{R}$ itsel. You probably know the following examples but the principle is very general.

Consider $C_b$ the space of continuous and bounded functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, with the norm of uniform convergence $\lVert \cdot \lVert_\infty$. Given a Cauchy sequence $f_n$, you know then that $f_n(x)$ is a real Cauchy sequence for all $x$ and it allows you to defined $f(x)$ as the limit (using that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete) of this sequence. Thus, you have define a function $f$ and then can show that your Cauchy sequence converges to that limit.

Another example that doesn't use the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. To show that the space $L^p$ of measurable functions with finite $L^p$-norm is complete, you can proceed the following way. Given a Cauchy sequence for the $L^p$ norm, you show that a subsequence converges almost surely, which defines clearly your limit object, and then show that the whole sequence converges.

Very often, you will have to follow that plan: construct your limit, and show that your

Answer (score 0):

Classic three-steps proof once you take a Cauchy sequence in your space:

(i) find a candidate for your limit (limit something that sounds the right possible limit for the third step),

(ii) show it belongs to the space (definition of being in the space),

(iii) show your sequence *actually* converges to it (definition of cenvergence).

Comment: Thanks, Ton. But I guess for my problem, finding the candidate limit is the difficult part.

Comment: What you say in your question is what is the general technique, and the above is what (I believe and was told) is generally done. Finding the candidate (step (i)) depends on the _specific_ metric space you are checking completeness of. The begining of your proof is also wrong because you are basically assuming the result. The proof should be: Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy seq in $M$ (no limit is involved, THE key of Cauchy seq). Now using the property of a Cauchy sequence ($\forall \epsilon>0...$) and, likely, the triangle inequality find the candidate limit. Now proceed for point (ii).